# POST request gives wrong responce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post

This is code that sends photos to server from Unity.
I need to send:

- photo as byte64
- file type as string

this is response for my code:

```
$_POST = []

$_FILES = [
    0 => [
        'name' => 'target_file'
        'type' => 'application/octet-stream'..
    ]
    1 => [
        'name' => 'jpg'
        'type' => 'text/plain'...
    ]
]
```

I need to get:

```
$_POST = [
    'type_object' => 'jpg'
]
$_FILES = [
    'target_file' => [
        'name' => 'tt3.jpg'
        'type' => 'image/jpeg'..
    ]
]
```

This is code of mine:

```
// photo is saved to Texture2D tex 
bytes = tex.EncodeToJPG();

List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
//form1 = target_file
formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection(form1, bytes)); 

//form2 = type_object
//req2 = "jpg"
formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection(form2, req2)); 
//siteAddress - "https://api...
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(siteAddress, formData);
www.chunkedTransfer = false;

yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

For the file you have to use a different constructor of [`MultipartFormFileSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html) and additionally pass the formname and content type. Something like e.g.

```c#
// form1 = "ttf3"
// req2 = "jpg"
formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("target_file", bytes, $"{form1}.{req2}", "image/jpg"));
```

---

By making the second one a [`MultipartFormFileSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html) it is treated as additional file with the string content `jpg`.

For the simple string values you rather want to use a [`MultipartFormDataSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormDataSection-ctor.html). Something like

```c#
// req2 = "jpg"
formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection($"type_object={req2}"));
```

Also see the example in [Sending a form to an HTTP server (POST)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html)

---

*Note: Typed on phone so no chance to test but I hope the idea gets clear*